# How to display major ticks even if the label is not showing up?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I set labelsize big enough to see, but by doing this, i omitted some of the major ticks. For example, in the first subplot there's space to place a major tick in 10<sup>-3</sup>, but i think the labelsize force matplot to omit it. I'm fine with omitting the label, but is there a way to show the major tick?

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7,1, sharey =False, sharex=True,layout='constrained')
loc = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,subs=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),numticks=12)
axis=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
color_data =['b.','g.', 'r.','c.','m.','y.','k.']
color_fit =['b','g', 'r','c','m','y','k']
for i,c_data,c_fit,r in zip(axis,color_data,color_fit,rapidez):
    axs[i].plot(n_eixo[i],Pn_fit[i],c_fit)
    axs[i].plot(list_n[i],list_PB[i],c_data,markersize=10)
    axs[i].set_yscale('log')
    axs[i].set_xlim(xmin=0)
    axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
    axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
    axs[i].set_xticks(np.arange(0,625,25))
    axs[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12,size=8,direction='in', bottom=True, left=True)
    axs[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8,direction='in')
```

[image]

Edit 1:

I've found a way to fix it! But i had to fix it manually...

I set yticks for each plot that omitted major ticks:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(7,1, sharey =False, sharex=True,layout='constrained')
loc = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,subs=(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8),numticks=12)
axis=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
color_data =['b.','g.', 'r.','c.','m.','y.','k.']
color_fit =['b','g', 'r','c','m','y','k']
for i,c_data,c_fit,r in zip(axis,color_data,color_fit,rapidez):
    axs[i].plot(n_eixo[i],Pn_fit[i],c_fit)
    axs[i].plot(list_n[i],list_PB[i],c_data,markersize=10)
    axs[i].set_yscale('log')
    axs[i].set_xlim(xmin=0)
    axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
    axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())
    axs[i].set_xticks(np.arange(0,625,25))
    axs[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=12,size=8,direction='in', bottom=True, left=True)
    axs[i].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8,direction='in')
#-----------------------Here------------------------- 
axs[0].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(2, 5, 1)])
axs[1].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(2, 5, 1)])
axs[2].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(2, 5, 1)])
axs[3].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(2, 5, 1)])
axs[5].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(3, 6, 1)])
#----------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

It seems that there's room for more major ticks in some plots, but it's quite boring to select them manually. The whole point of this is to let the plot size unchanged while inserting those missing major ticks, because if i put too many, the plot gets resized as bellow:

[image]

If anyone knows how to fix it in a simpler way, please let me know!

Comment: 1. If you have an answer you can post it as an answer rather than an edit. 2. Why not put `axs[i].set_yticks([10**(-x) for x in range(2, 5, 1)])` in your `for` loop with everything else?